# Numpy array as a python class property - cannot copy array within class function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, properties, copy

I have a python class that uses a numpy array as a class property. The numpy array changes as calculations are completed during a model simulation. I need to copy the array at certain critical states to evaluate changes. For some reason when I use the numpy.copy() function I am only able to create a reference to the numpy array and not a copy of the array as needed.

Below is some code in attempt to replicate this issue:

```
class TestNumpyPropertyBase(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rand_arr = np.array(np.random.rand(5, 5, 2) * 1000, dtype=int)


class TestNumpyPropertySub(TestNumpyPropertyBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def reset_rand_arr_slice(self):
        self.rand_arr[:3, :3, :] = np.array(np.random.rand(3, 3, 2) * 1000, dtype=int)

    def get_rand_arr_states(self):
        rand_arr_state1 = self.rand_arr.copy()
        self.reset_rand_arr_slice()
        rand_arr_state2 = self.rand_arr.copy()
        return rand_arr_state1, rand_arr_state2


test_np_prop = TestNumpyPropertySub()
arr_st1, arr_st2 = test_np_prop.get_rand_arr_states()
print(arr_st1[:, :, 1])
print(arr_st2[:, :, 1])
```

This is essentially very close to the structure I have with my code with a Super class that defines the numpy array and a sub class that does the calculations. I have replaced the model calculations with a simple function that changes the array to some random numbers (reset_rand_arr_slice()). Additionally the arrays in the actual model are typically much larger (400 X 40 X 10). This code actually works and below is the output with the first 3X3 portions of the copied arrays different, which is expected.

```
[[149 358 164 336 556]
 [377  82 584 811 542]
 [257 704 674 995  72]
 [811  23 948 525 425]
 [929 248 767 303 214]]
[[574 923 383 336 556]
 [ 40 875 296 811 542]
 [933  46  23 995  72]
 [811  23 948 525 425]
 [929 248 767 303 214]]
```

With my model code the modified portions of the array are identical to property array, which indicates that the property array is not actually being copied, but is just a reference to the property array.  I have looked over the code extensively to determine how my code might differ from this example, but I can't seem to find anything. The copied arrays actually have different reference numbers, which makes me believe they are copies, but the values of the copies are the same as the property array at the end of the simulation.

Also, since the array is a property of a class, I have also tried using deepcopy() by adding the following code to my base class as recommended in some previous posts, but that does not seem to help either.

```
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        cls = self.__class__
        result = cls.__new__(cls)
        memo[id(self)] = result
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            setattr(result, k, cp.deepcopy(v, memo))
        return result
```

If anyone has any insight as what might cause this issue and how it might be resolved it would be greatly appreciated. -Thanks!

Comment: We need to see code that actually reproduces the bug, not code that works fine. It doesn't matter if the code is "essentially very close to the structure" of your real code - if it doesn't reproduce the bug, it's not close enough in the ways that would let us help you.

Comment: I often use the `arr.__array_interface__['data']` to illustraste whether an array is a view or copy of some other array.  `arr.base` can also be useful.  I don't know what you mean by 'reference number'.